# Provide three argument to one option using getopts in bash

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I am trying to process a command line using getopts in bash. I have to pass three arguments after -w option. For example, -w 1 do loop. It should print one line before and after each line from loop that contains the pattern do. This is the code I have now:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=`ls | grep ^$1$`
pattern=`cat $file |grep -B$2 -A$2 $3`
while getopts":w:" opt
do
case $opt in
    w) $2=$OPTARG ; pattern=$OPTARG ; file=$OPTARG ;array=($OPTARG)
    ;;
    *)echo " usage: -w <pattern>"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
done

echo "${#array[@]}"
echo "line: $2, pattern: $pattern, file: $file"
```

Is there anyway to retrieve the three variables from one flag?

Answer (score 3):

Only one argument can be passed to an option, but you may specify a,b,c and later temporarily set IFS to ',' and use read to split the argument a,b,c into three words.

For example:

```
$ OPTARG="1,do,loop"
$ IFS=, read n patt file <<<"$OPTARG"
$ echo $n; echo $patt; echo $file
1
do
loop
```